# INSERT INTO statement doesn't post data to table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post data to a table in my database, but there is no error messages as to why the data is not posted. I have inserted data into the table in phpmyadmin and this data is printed with the result while loop, but data will not post to the table.

```
<!-- form to take input-->
    <form name='form1' method='post'>
    Name:
    <input type='text' name='Name' id='name' /> <br />
    Comment:
    <input type='text' name='Comment' id='comment' /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" id='submit'>
    </form>
    <!-- start php-->
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $name = $_POST['Name'];
                $comment = $_POST['Comment'];
            }

            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "kodie", "hill1124", "comments");
            if(mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySql: ". mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW()");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM commenttable"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $hash = $result;
            echo "<table>";
            if($hash = NULL)
            {
                echo "null";
            }
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {   
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" .  $row['comment'] . "</td><td>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
            }

            echo "</table>"; 

            mysqli_close($con); 

    ?>
```

I am unsure why it won't post, I don't think it is permissions but I am new to using mysql and don't understand why the statement compiles without errors but doesn't actually put the data on the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put `or die(mysqli_error($con))` after `mysqli_query(...)` so you see the error message from MySQL.

Comment: The problem is probably that `$comment` contains a quote character, which is breaking your syntax. You should use a prepared query or `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: You're missing a close paren  mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW())");

Comment: @Barmar self inducted SQL Injection.

Comment: Classic debug question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing `)` at the end of your `insert` statement:

```
mysqli_query
   ($con, 
    "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW())");
    //                                               This one ^
```

Comment: I had noticed that earlier, but the program I was using to write the code color coded it as closed. This fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In order to `INSERT` data in your database you need to adjust the insert query.
What you have now:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW()");
```

Should be

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name', '$comment', NOW())");
```

You should also consider using `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent `SQL-injection`

So:

```
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$comment = $_POST['Comment'];
```

Becomes:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name']);
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Comment']);
```

You can also take a look at the following:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php;
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php (removes left over spaces);
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php (**Optional** removes html tags from string)

***UPDATE***

```
<!-- form to take input-->
<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="name"> <br>
    Comment:
    <input type="text" name="Comment" id="comment"> <br>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<!-- start php-->

<?php
if($_POST) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "kodie", "hill1124", "comments");

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['Name']));
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['Comment']));

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($comment)) {
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW())");

        // Check if the query succeeded
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM commenttable";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $hash = $result;
            echo "<table>";
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong: '. mysqli_error($con); // Echo the error (You could replace echo with die())
        }
    }

    if ($hash = NULL) {
        echo "null";
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['comment'] . "</td><td>" . $row['timestamp'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con); // this is not necessary
}
?>
```

Comment: if the table only has the 3 columns it is not required to put the columns in the query.

Comment: @FunkDoc oke edited that

Comment: cool. this is the correct answer and good to point out escaping the inputs.

Comment: Your closing parenthesis should be inside the quote in your "should be" example.

Comment: OP has mentioned "but there is no error messages"?

Comment: By the way, after your corrections the OP will be inserting heaps of emtpy rows in the db. Everything should be inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` statement.

Answer (score 0):

See the line `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW()");`

You havnt Closed the `mysqli_query()`.

It must be `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW()"));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure User "kodie" have [privileges](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql) to do INSERT

Answer (score -1):

Missing parenthesis in

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW()");
```

should be

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO commenttable VALUES ('$name','$comment',NOW()")); // missing )
```

Comment: Please use code blocks in your answers.